# How to connect remote oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

I have Oracle 10g installed on a windows server with a remote desktop virtual machine.
I buy a hosting plan and host my php website on it, which is another server.

I want to connect oracle database form that window server with my php website on another server.

I have added the oci8 extension on my panel where my php files are hosting.

I have static live public IP of the windows server where Oracle is installed.

I want to connect them. But I got the error from the php file which says

```
TNS: no listener ORA-12541 error.
```

But when I connect php file to that oracle from my localhost with wamp server it connects but on the panel live it gives that error.

```
$username="uerp_adm";
$password="DBPASSWORD";
$tns2 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERPUBLICIP WHERE ORACLE IS INSTALLED)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = orcl)))";
$conn=oci_connect($username,$password, $connstring);
if($conn){
  echo 'CONNECTED';
}
else{
  echo 'NOT CONNECTED';
}
```

Comment: check the Status of you listener ` lsnrctl Status`

Comment: I had check that on the sever where oracle is installed but its running

Comment: you should check it on your machine where you are trying to connect to oracle

Comment: As hotfix mentioned, you want to test connectivity from the machine you're using to try to connect. There may be a firewall or network configuration issue that is preventing you from connecting. You can test using the TNSPING utility, more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/connect.htm#NETAG378

Comment: But how can I check this on cpanel, because I want to connect oracle from cpanel using php